# Google Maps onResume

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm using google maps in my android app. Everything is fine but when i have no GPS service enabled i show a snackbar message to enable. When i enable GPS and turn back in my Fragment der map dosen't return to my location automaticly only when i press the location button.

I tried to solve the problem by using a thread in my update method but nothing. changed. Sometimes it works but sometimes isn't good enough.

my onCreate:

```
 public  void init(){
    gps = new GPSTracker();
    gps.init(mActivity,mActivity);
    if (!gps.canGetLocation()) {
        gps.showSettingsAlert(mActivity,rootView);
    }else {
        initMap();
    }
```

my initMap

```
 private void initMap(){
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
            moveSearchCircle(new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude()));
            updateMapPosition();
            googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
            addMarker();
        }
    });
}
```

updateMapPosition

```
 private void updateMapPosition(){
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude()), 15));
   }
```

onResume

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    init();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude()` returns zero values, and focus of your map's camera trying to set to this place. 
Usually, get device location operation takes some time and you should do this asynchronously. 
So, please, check your `GPSTracker` class and find async methods, or see [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).